# Implicit conversion not taking place for Play Framework Lang in controller

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a view that takes in an implicit `Lang`, needed for Play's `Messages` object. The signature of this view is:

```
@()(implicit lang: Lang)
```

Then I have a controller that needs to create the view:

```
def createView = Action { request =>
  Ok(views.html.showView())
}
```

And then I have an implicit method that I want called to create the `Lang` that the view needs:

```
implicit def getLangFromRequest(request: RequestHeader): Lang = {
  request.cookies.get("lang") match {
    case Some(cookie) => Lang(cookie.value)
    case None => Lang("en") // Default
  }
}
```

In other words, the method is supposed to get the language from the cookie if it can or use a default otherwise (I've trimmed out error handling for this question).

However, this implicit conversion isn't taking place. I know that it's able to implicitly convert, because by creating an implicit variable in the controller works:

```
def createView = Action { request =>
  implicit val lang: Lang = request
  Ok(views.html.showView())
}
```

But I'd rather not have to add this boiler plate line everywhere. Presumably I must explicitly call the method because there's some global `Lang` object that is being used before an implicit conversion.

What are my options here to avoid having to repeat this `implicit val lang: Lang = request` in every controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Play documentation

> If you have an implicit Request in the scope, it will provide an
>   implicit Lang value corresponding to the preferred language extracted
>   from the Accept-Language header and matching one of the application
>   supported languages.

So you need to change your action to

```
def createView = Action { implicit request =>
  Ok(views.html.showView())
}
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Having to call `implicit val lang: Lang = request` for each controller seems like a lot of work but when you think about it, not really, you already call the `Action` method (which accepts as a parameter a `Request => Result` function) whenever you create a new action.

Write a `trait` that would do all the heavy logic of finding the language, mix it into all controllers and instead of using the `Action` method, use a method that you write in that trait, that takes in a `Request => Lang => Result` function, does the logic for the languages and then applies the function parameter to the request in scope. Something like this:

```
trait Internationalization { subj: Controller =>

  def withLanguage(f: => Request[AnyContent] => Lang => Result) = Action { implicit request =>
    val lang = request.cookies.get("lang") match {
      case Some(cookie) => Lang(cookie.value)
      case None => Lang("en") // Default
    }
    f(request)(lang)
  }

}
```

Then, instead of `def action = Action { ... }`, just mix in the trait and use:

```
def action = withLanguage { request => implicit lang => 
   Ok(views.html.showView())
}
```